# Failed to remove extra spaces using wildcards in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I have multiple instances of [word]- [word] in a text, e.g. self- interest instead of self-interest, which is the correct form. I am trying to remove the extraneous space after the stroke using MS Word's wildcards. In the Find and Replace box I enter:

> Find: *- *
>   Replace with: \1-\2

However, it doesn't work. What is the correct form to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

## VBA:

Run `WrapReplace` in Word document.

```
Sub WrapReplace()
    Call RegExpReplace("(\w+)\-\s(\w+)", "$1-$2")
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub RegExpReplace(pattern As String, Backreference As String)
    Dim strReplacement As String
    Set oRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With oRegExp
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With

    Set matches = oRegExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content)
 
    For Each match In matches
        Set matchRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    
        strReplacement = oRegExp.Replace(match.Value, Backreference)
    
        With matchRange.Find
            .Text = match.Value
            .Replacement.Text = strReplacement
        
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You omitted to tell Word what the parts \1 and \2 are.  Add round brackets around the asterisk hyphen, and the asterisk, but leave the space between.  In your Replace with you don't need the hyphen as this is now captured as part of \1.

[image]